# Creating NestedQuery for List in Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

How to create a query using `QueryBuilders` for a nested `List`.
Something like that:

```
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
...
QueryBuilders.matchQuery(...);
```

I need to find a document where `code` equals "test" and `value` containing "nested" text.
Sample data in a nested class:
`code` = "test"
`value` = "my nested value"

Below are the class definitions.

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;

@Data
@Document(indexName = "MY_DOCUMENT")
public class MyDocument {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, name = "SUB_DOC")
    private List<SubDocument> subDoc;

    ....

}
```

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;

@Data
class SubDocument {

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, name = "VALUE")
    private String value;

}
```

Dependencies from `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Additionally, is it possible to create this type of query in a form acceptable to Lucene?
Something like that:

```
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.AbstractQueryBuilder;
...
String stringQuery = "+SUB_DOC.VALUE:... +SUB_DOC.CODE:...";
AbstractQueryBuilder<?> q = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(stringQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are explicitly asking for a solution using Elasticsearch  `QueryBuilders` this is not really related to Spring Data Elasticsearch. You are just using Spring Data Elasticsearch to pass the Elasticsearch query down to the Elasticsearch client.

If you would use the Spring Data Elasticsearch classes, you could build a query like this:

```java
var query = new CriteriaQuery(
    new Criteria("subDoc.code").is("test")
        .and("subDoc.value").contains("nested"));
var searchHits = operations.search(query, MyDocument.class);
```